# Python Packaging - NameError

Tags: python, python-packaging

I am trying to build a Python package using [this tutorial](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html). This is the folder structure:

```
testpackage\
       testpackage\
              __init__.py
       setup.py
       bin\
          test.sh
```

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='testpackage',
  version='0.1',
  description='Test package',
  url='http://github.com/storborg/testpackage',
  author='ABcd',
  author_email='abcd@xyz.com',
  license='Private',
  packages=['testpackage'],
  scripts=['bin/test.sh'],
  zip_safe=False)
```

**__init__.py**

```
from subprocess import call
import shlex
def joke():
    call(shlex.split('bash bin/test.sh testfun'))
    return (u'This is a sample package')
```

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

testfun()
{
    echo "QQQQQQQQQQQQ"
}

"$@"
```

I ran the `pip install .` command from the root `testpackage` folder, and got installed successfully. Then I accessed python prompt from the same folder and called the `joke()` function, it got executed and printed the text messages. When I access the python prompt from a different folder and call this function, its throwing a `NameError`.

```
>>> import testpackage
>>> testpackage.joke()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/testpackage/__init__.py",       line 2, in joke
call(shlex.split('bash test.sh testfun'))
NameError: global name 'call' is not defined
```

Why this happening? Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution.

I uninstalled the `testpackage` using `sudo pip uninstall testpackage`.

Then I installed it again, `sudo pip install .`

Whenever I am modifying the package, I uninstall and again install the package. Previously I was trying to reinstall the package without uninstalling it. I thought it will get updated, But it was not.

Tested it, Now working fine.